# Why in flutter, setting property mainAxisAlignment to center for column also center it horizontally?

Tags: android, windows, flutter, frontend

I'm new to flutter, While practising the row and column widget I encountered this problem. It's said that setting `mainAxisAlignment` to center in a flutter column will center the children vertically, Why when I added a row as a children, the column also centers horizontally while the row children does not?

Does anyone know why?

Here is the code

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Exercise row & column"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("Text 1"),
          Text("Text 2"),
          Text("Text 3"),
          Row(children: <Widget>[
            Text("Text 4"),
            Text("Text 5"),
            Text("Text 6"),
          ])
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
```

Here is the result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

your code seems to be good. I tested it and it worked fine, sometimes flutter just holds cache and do not do changes that are clearly visible. try `flutter clean` then re-run the project. it will solve your problem :)

Answer (score -1):

This is because the Row widget takes up the entire width and its children are aligned horizontally.

In order to center align the **Row Widget**'s children, added a *mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center* property to the row widget.

Comment: Umm yes I know but.. aren't text1 text2 and text3 supposed to be on the left without adding crossAxisAlignment.start? if I remove the crossAxisAlignment then the text1,text2,text3 is on the center.. I don't know why but text1 text2 and text3 are clearly not the row's children..

Comment: As I mentioned, the Row widget spans the entire width while the Text widget will only span up to the width of the text it contains. Text1, Text2, and Text2 are abiding by the mainAxisAlignment property, in this case, the vertical axis as the parent widget is a Column.

Comment: column has its own axis. it should built from left if crossAxisAlignment is set to start no matter if there is a Row in children or not.